# Let $\mu ^{*}$ be a arbitrary outer measure is necessarily satisfied? $\mu ^*(A \cup B) + \mu^{*}(A \cap B) \leq \mu^{*}(A)+\mu ^{*}(B)$

Tags: measure-theory, outer-measure

> Let $\mu ^{*}$ be a arbitrary outer measure in a set $X$ and $A,B \subset X$, the following inequality is necessarily satisfied?
> $$\mu ^*(A \cup B) + \mu^{*}(A \cap B) \leq \mu^{*}(A)+\mu ^{*}(B)$$

I know that if $A$ (or $B$) is $\mu ^{*}-$ measurable then the equality holds but i try to show that supposing that $A,B$ are not $\mu^{*}-$ measurables.

I proceded by cases:

Case $1$: $A \subset B$ in this case $A \cup B=B$ and $A \cap B=A$ then
$$\mu ^*(A \cup B) + \mu^{*}(A \cap B) =\mu ^*( B) + \mu^{*}(A) $$
Case $2$: $A \cap B =\emptyset$ in this case $\mu^{*}(A \cap B)=0$ and for subadditivity
$$\mu ^{*}(A \cup B) + \mu^{*}(A \cap B)=\mu^{*}(A \cup B)+0\leq \mu^{*}(A)+\mu ^{*}(B)$$
Case $3$: $A \cap B = \emptyset$ in this case i have problems,
intuitively I think it could be true but the term $\mu^{*}(A \cap B)$ is the problem, i search counterexamples but i not sure.

Any hint or help i will be very grateful.

Comment: Case 3 is the same as Case 2. Did you mean to write $\ne$ in Case 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Counterexample.** Let $X=\{x,y,z\}$ be a $3$-element set. For $A\subseteq X$ define
$$\mu^*(A)=\begin{cases}
0\text{ if }A=\varnothing,\\
1\text{ if }\varnothing\ne A\ne X,\\
2\text{ if }A=X.\\
\end{cases}$$
Then $\mu^*$ is an outer measure. If $A=\{x,y\}$ and $B=\{y,z\}$, then $\mu^*(A\cup B)+\mu^*(A\cap B)=2+1=3$, and $\mu^*(A)+\mu^*(B)=1+1=2$.